# how to store user {name} if the user doesn't have {username} telegram bot python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

how to store user {name} if the user doesn't have {username} telegram bot python?

**i'am using python 3.8 and telegram-python-bot library!**

**i tried this but its doesn't work >>>**

```
user = ({update.effective_user.username})
name = ({update.effective_user.first_name})

if user == 'None':
    print (user)
    with open('BOTUsers.txt') as addname:
        contentsN = addname.read()
        search_wordN = (name)
        addname.close
        if (str (search_wordN)) in contentsN:
            print ("[=] Name Already Exist!")
        else:
            filename = open ("BOTUsers.txt" , 'a')
            filename.write(str(name))
            filename.write("\n")
            filename.close
            print ("[+] New Name added!")
            CounterUser += 1
else:
    with open('BOTUsers.txt') as adduser:
        contentsU = adduser.read()
        search_wordU = (user)
        adduser.close
        if (str (search_wordU)) in contentsU:
            print ("[=] User Already Exist!")
```

*i want the code to check if the user was 'none' store its name instead*

Comment: it should be `if not user:` instead of `if user == 'None':`

Comment: @GhostOps No brother i want the code to check if the user was 'none' store its name instead

Comment: or `str(user) in ('None', '')`

Comment: @GhostOps suggestion was actually a good one though

Comment: @sMx_7d i think u need more python knowledge to understand my code suggestion in my comment

Comment: Try what i said and tell us the results

Comment: @GhostOps np i will test what u suggest

Comment: @GhostOps still worng , i didn't got what i was want for .

Comment: @rv.kvetch can u explain more about this code ? `str(user) in ('None', '')`

Comment: its actually (i guess) `if not user[0][0]:` try it, but why are you putting a value inside a set and nesting it again in a tuple?

Comment: well, it's more or less the same as the one previously suggested. there is a slight difference for ex. if `user` is already a string with a literal value `None`, it'll be true with this approach but not with the other one.

Comment: @GhostOps lol, at first look I thought it was a `jinja` syntax with double curly braces {{ that I am also familiar with

Comment: @GhostOps bcz if u r username was empty soo the telegram automatically will make the user 'None' and i'am making a bot and a lot of ppl doesn't have username so u will know what i will see in  BOTUsers.txt

Comment: I'd suggest trying it just like `user = update.effective_user.username` and doing the same check I added above

Comment: if you need case-insensitive comparison you can do `str(user).lower() in ('none', '')` - this basically converts `user` to string (in case it's not already one) then does a lookup to see if the value is found in the tuple.

Comment: you dont process the id of the user. Is this on purpose? username of an user can change, the user.id of an user account never changes.

Comment: @gunnar247 yep i can but idk how to find the user by it?

Comment: When you replace `({update.effective_user.username})` with `({update.effective_user.id})` then your user variable contains the id.

Comment: @gunnar247 yep i know but you can't find the user by his id in telegram

Comment: pls if anyone know how to find anybody by id tell us pls

Comment: Did these users ever interact with your bot?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Can you write the user_id instead of first_name or username into BOTUsers.txt? Then you can read the file with the user_id as SearchWord

```
# user = ({update.effective_user.username})
# name = ({update.effective_user.first_name})
user_id = ({update.effective_user.id})
is_user_in_file = False

with open('BOTUsers.txt') as adduser:
    contentsU = adduser.read()
    search_wordU = (user_id)
    adduser.close
    if (str (search_wordU)) in contentsU:
        is_user_id_in_file = True

if not is_user_id_in_file:
    print (user_id)
    with open('BOTUsers.txt') as add_id:
        contentsN = add_id.read()
        search_wordN = (user_id)
        add_id.close
        if (str (search_wordN)) in contentsN:
            print ("[=] Name Already Exist!")
        else:
            filename = open ("BOTUsers.txt" , 'a')
            # filename.write(str(name))
            filename.write(str(user_id))
            filename.write("\n")
            filename.close
            print ("[+] New User ID added!")
```